# Move file XSLT - Create new XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

When I'm doing a convertion with XSLT, I need to put in the output directory, another XSLT file. This XSLT file always have the same code.

I don't know if I can copy and paste a file with XSLT. I tried to create a new document with `<xsl:result-document>` but it's seems not appropriate

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use

```
<xsl:result-document href="outputdir/sheet.xsl">
  <xsl:copy-of select="document('sheet.xsl')"/>
</xsl:result-document>
```

then a copy of `sheet.xsl` will be created in `outputdir`.